How to optimize ibase query with Tree subconsults
We have a complex and large database, without any control over the structure. We can simply read.
We need to do a product query that involves several cross tables. Specifically, know about all the products you buy, sales and stock. With some filters that I believe do not affect the query.
The specific query is about the form and the performance obtained, which I do not understand because it degrades terribly if we try to do everything with a single query.
Broken down, the 3 queries we have to ask are:
Product sales:
    WITH
        SubConsulta1 AS (
        SELECT
            cantidad AS cantidad,
            importefra / (1 + IVAfra) AS importesinivafra,
            IDPRODUCTO AS IDProducto,
            FechaHora AS FechaHora,
            idBase AS idBase
        FROM lineasventa LV
        JOIN ventas V ON V.iDVenta = LV.IDVenta
        WHERE
            V.fechahora BETWEEN '2024/01/01-00-00' AND '2024/04/18-23-59' AND
            V.idbase = 1)
    SELECT
        codigoproducto AS CodiProducte,
        concepto AS Concepte,
        SUM(S1.cantidad)  AS importesinivafra,
        SUM(S1.importesinivafra)  AS cantidad
    FROM PRODUCTOS P
    JOIN SubConsulta1 S1 ON P.IDPRODUCTO = S1.IDPRODUCTO
    WHERE
        P.activo = 1 AND
        P.idfamilia = '106'
    GROUP BY
        codigoproducto, concepto
    ORDER BY
        P.CODIGOPRODUCTO

Results Execute time = 22s 636ms
Product purchases:
    SELECT
        codigoproducto AS CodiProducte,
        concepto AS Concepte,
        SUM(importe) AS ImporteCompra,
        SUM(cantidad) AS CantidadCompra
    FROM PRODUCTOS P
    LEFT JOIN LineasCompra LC on LC.idproducto = P.idproducto
    LEFT JOIN Compras C ON C.idcompra = LC.idcompra
    WHERE
        P.activo = 1 AND
        P.idfamilia = '106' AND
        C.fechahora BETWEEN '2024/01/01-00-00' AND '2024/04/18-23-59' AND
        C.IDBASE = 1
    GROUP BY 
        codigoproducto, concepto
    ORDER BY 
        P.CODIGOPRODUCTO

Results Execute time = 1s 591ms
Product stocks:
    SELECT
        P.IDPRODUCTO AS IDPRODUCTO,
        P.CODIGOPRODUCTO AS CODIGOPRODUCTO,
        SUM(E.UNIDADES) AS EXISTENCIES
    FROM PRODUCTOS P
    JOIN EXISTENCIAS E ON P.IDPRODUCTO = E.IDProducto
    JOIN propietariosproducto PP ON P.IDPRODUCTO = PP.IDPRODUCTO
    WHERE
        P.activo = 1 AND
        PP.idproveedor = 1
    GROUP BY
        IDPRODUCTO, CODIGOPRODUCTO
    ORDER BY
        P.IDPRODUCTO

Results Execute time = 16ms
But when we try to get a single query with these 3 queries,
    WITH

        SubConsulta1 AS (
            SELECT
                cantidad AS cantidadC,
                importe AS importe,
                IDPRODUCTO AS IDProducto,
                C.FechaHora AS FechaHora
            FROM lineascompra LC
            JOIN compras C ON C.IDCompra = LC.IDcompra
            WHERE
                C.fechahora BETWEEN '2024/01/01-00-00' AND '2024/04/18-23-59' AND
                C.idbase = '1'),

        SubConsulta2 AS (
        SELECT
            cantidad AS cantidadV,
            importefra / (1 + IVAfra) AS importefra,
            IVAfra AS IVAfra,
            IDPRODUCTO AS IDProducto,
            FechaHora AS FechaHora,
            idBase AS idBase
        FROM lineasventa LV
        JOIN ventas V ON V.iDVenta = LV.IDVenta    
        WHERE
            V.fechahora BETWEEN '2024/01/01-00-00' AND '2024/04/18-23-59' AND
            V.idbase = 1),

        SubConsulta3 AS (
        SELECT
            P.CODIGOPRODUCTO,
            E.UNIDADES AS EXISTENCIES,
            E.IDPRODUCTO AS IDPRODUCTO,
            E.IDALmacen
        FROM PRODUCTOS P
        JOIN EXISTENCIAS E ON P.IDPRODUCTO = E.IDProducto
        WHERE
            P.activo = 1 AND
            P.idfamilia = '106' AND
            E.IDALMACEN = '1')
    SELECT
        P.codigoproducto AS CodiProducte,
        P.concepto AS Concepte,
        SUM(S1.importe) AS ImporteCompra,
        SUM(S1.cantidadC) AS CantidadCompra,
        SUM(S2.cantidadV) AS CantidadVenta,
        SUM(S2.importefra) AS ImporteVenta,
        S3.EXISTENCIES AS Existencias
    FROM PRODUCTOS P
    JOIN SubConsulta1 S1 ON P.IDPRODUCTO = S1.IDPRODUCTO
    JOIN SubConsulta2 S2 ON P.IDPRODUCTO = S2.IDPRODUCTO
    JOIN SubConsulta3 S3 ON P.IDPRODUCTO = S3.IDPRODUCTO
    WHERE
        P.activo = 1 AND
        P.idfamilia = '106'
    GROUP BY
        P.codigoproducto, P.concepto, S3.Existencies
    ORDER BY
        P.CODIGOPRODUCTO

the execution time becomes hours!!!.
Are we doing something wrong when trying to integrate the 3 queries?
Or would a better approach be to get the data from the 3 queries separately and merge the results by code in PHP?
Edited:
I have narrowed the search down to just a few days. (fechahora BETWEEN '2024/04/01-00-00' AND '2024/04/18-23-59') in Sub1 and Sub2, and the Analitycs results are:
Plan
"PLAN SORT (JOIN (S1 C INDEX (I_COMPRAS_FECHAHORA, RDB$FOREIGN114), S1 LC INDEX (RDB$FOREIGN138), P INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY56), S3 P INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY56), S3 E INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY32), S2 LV INDEX (RDB$FOREIGN152), S2 V INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY92)))"
Adapted Plan
"PLAN SORT (JOIN (S1 C INDEX (I_COMPRAS_FECHAHORA, FK_COMPRAS_BASES), S1 LC INDEX (FK_LINEASCOMPRA_COMPRAS), P INDEX (PK_PRODUCTOS), S3 P INDEX (PK_PRODUCTOS), S3 E INDEX (PK_EXISTENCIAS), S2 LV INDEX (FK_LINEASVENTA_PRODUCTOS), S2 V INDEX (PK_VENTAS)))"
Performance info
Prepare time = 0ms
**Execute time = 14m 26s 134ms**
Avg fetch time = 48.118,56 ms
Current memory = 102.705.560
Max memory = 440.708.908
Memory buffers = 9.999
Reads from disk to cache = 4.669.873
Writes from cache to disk = 1.079
Fetches from cache = 0


Query Time
Prepare       : 0,00 ms
Execute       : 866.134,00 ms
Avg fetch time: 48.118,56 ms

Memory
Current: 113.875.668
Max    : 440.708.908
Buffers: 9.999

Operations
Read   : 4.669.873
Writes : 1.079
Fetches: 0
Marks  : 1.281

Query optimization, or alternative solution to obtain a single table with all the required data from the 'products' table

Did you look at plans?

In the merged query no, because I really don't know how long the consultation would take. Many hours, and I saturate the BD in the meantime. Is there anything important in the plans for this question?

In the slowest query of the 3, in the plans I have the following information:

Plan
PLAN SORT (JOIN (S1 V INDEX (I_SALES_DATETIME, RDB$FOREIGN232), S1 LV INDEX (RDB$FOREIGN154), P INDEX (RDB$PRIMARY56)))

Adapted Plan
SORT PLAN (JOIN (S1 V INDEX (I_SALES_DATETIME, FK_SALES_BASES), S1 LV INDEX (FK_SALESLINES_SALES), P INDEX (PK_PRODUCTS)))*************
I will try to finish the joint consultation to see if I can provide more information. Although I don't know if the system won't crash if I have hours with the query...

Optimization of queries require deep knowledge of database and optimizer. It is not something you can read in a crystal ball. Yes, in this case the best way would be to merge data in PHP.
